# Android Studio: proguard line numbers wrong, not completly obfuscating

Tags: android-studio, proguard

*NEW:* the main thing I'm looking for is a fix for the wrong line numbers. That is making it next to impossible to pinpoint various crashes.

At some point in the past, my proguard obfuscation stopped working properly, or so it seems.  In the following log file snip, notice that my identifiers BasicList and ImageClick are showing up in the file.  Yet, it's clear Proguard is running since there are obfucscations present.

Second, for the BasicList line, it shows a line number of 6218.   My source file has no where near that many lines.  Just to be clear, it's not a character postition either.

```
E/InputEventReceiver( 3814): Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814):  at com.perinote.perinote2.BasicList.a(SourceFile:6218)
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814):  at com.perinote.perinote2.ae.onClick(SourceFile:266)
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814):  at com.perinote.widgets.ImageClick.onTouchEvent(SourceFile:1156)
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
E/MessageQueue-JNI( 3814):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
```

My proguard-project.txt has the following

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { ... stuff ... }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a very similar problem, with the *Exception dispatching input Event*, and for solve it, I went adding to proguard each folder with the code, using this line:

```
-keep class !com.MyPackage.folderActivity { *; }
```

In case that the obfuscation failed after add a folder, you can add class by class of the same folder using something very similar:

```
-keep class !com.MyPackage.folderActivity.ActivityOne { *; }
```

at the beginning it's a very slow process, but then it´s easy to maintain.

Well, I hope this be useful.

Comment: My understanding of "keep" is that it instructs proguard to not strip the code out of the app, which it will do if it finds the code is unused. I'm not sure what this would have to do with line numbers. However, the next time I find log output with bad line numbers, I'll try this. If it works, I'll be happy to award you the right answer credit !

Comment: you are right, but the "!" signal is one of the wildcards of proguard that works as a negator, so, in this case it says to proguard to do the opposite action, obfuscating only that folder or activity.  This can be useful for you, to find which class has too many dependencies that cause the error with high number lines.  On this link you can check more wildcards: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/usage.html

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, with an example: Let's say that you make double click on function "performClick", this will show you the code (from the api), in which that function is implemented on a class. This class has other dependencies (Import another class from the same api).  In a few cases I found that some functions that are part of the api, are more difficult to obfuscate, due to this deep level dependencies. I hope to be clear.